# Iterate returned c# serialized List<string> in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a webmethod which will read the first line in a csv file to get the column titles then store each item in the list which I will return to the ajax call. This is the code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string getAvailableSensors()
    {
        List<string> sensors = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string path = "C:\\.....\\TestData3.csv";
            string line;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                sensors = line.Split(',').ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string output = jss.Serialize(sensors);
        return output;
    }
```

This is what the data looks like when it is returned to the ajax call:
[image]

This is what my ajax looks like :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebSockets.aspx/getAvailableSensors",
            async: false,
            data: "{ }", // send an empty object for calls with no parameters
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                data = result.d;
                for (var i in result.d) {
                    sensors.push(result.d[i]);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

but this only populates the array 1 character at a time which is not what I am trying to do.

I cannot figure out how to iterate the damn json so that I can populate my `var sensors = new Array();` with the columns. ex( sensor[0] should be "Time", sensor[ 1 ] should be "X Accel LH" ) etc.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: not getting an error. More like having a problem iterating the returned data correctly. Every single idea I've tried only returns 1 character at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to make that string as an object. Use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to make it as object.

```
data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

In your case, you can use the data like a string array

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved a computer and a window. I haven't done this in a while so I forgot about jQuery.parseJSON

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX options you should set `dataType: 'json'` so that the response is automatically converted to JSON before being handed to your callback.  This is probably what you expected the `contentType` to do, but in reality that sets the type of the content being sent, not what you expect to be returned. You might also want to apply a `ScriptMethodAttribute` and specify the result being returned is JSON - I believe this will set the `Content-Type` header so that jQuery can automatically detect the format in the absence of specifying it in your options.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string getAvailableSensors()
{
   ...
}
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json", // <-- this
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "WebSockets.aspx/getAvailableSensors",
    async: false,
    data: "{ }", // send an empty object for calls with no parameters
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
        data = result.d;
        for (var i in result.d) {
            sensors.push(result.d[i]);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

If you're using a newer version of jQuery you might want to look into replacing your success and error callbacks with the `done` and `fail` methods.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json", // <-- this
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebSockets.aspx/getAvailableSensors",
        async: false,
        data: "{ }", // send an empty object for calls with no parameters
 })
 .done(function(result) {
     debugger;
     data = result.d;
     for (var i in result.d) {
          sensors.push(result.d[i]);
     }
 })
 .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
     alert("an error has occured: " + xhr.responseText);
 });
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I will definitely be remembering this for better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just return an `IList<string>` from your web method instead of serializing manually.

```
[WebMethod]
public static IList<string> getAvailableSensors()
{
    List<string> sensors = new List<string>();
    string path = "C:\\.....\\TestData3.csv";
    string line;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        sensors = line.Split(',').ToList();
    }
    return sensors;
}
```

Also, your error handling is not exaclty correct. For the client, the operation succeeded even if there is an error on server side. I just removed you try catch to let the exception propagate to the client.